# PHP XML SOAP request basic setup

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am working on a new plugin for getting shipping qoutes but have never done a XML/SOAP request with PHP.

The company sent over a sample request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.gts" xmlns:xsd="http://services.gts/xsd">

   <soap:Header/>

   <soap:Body>

      <ser:getRate>

         <!--Optional:-->

         <ser:rRequest>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:deliveryDate>05/29/2017</xsd:deliveryDate>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:destZipCode>83814</xsd:destZipCode>

            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

            <xsd:items>

               <!--Optional:-->

               <xsd:item_class>85</xsd:item_class>

               <!--Optional:-->

               <xsd:nmfc>?</xsd:nmfc>

               <!--Optional:-->

               <xsd:weight>100</xsd:weight>

            </xsd:items>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:origZipCode>15065-1840</xsd:origZipCode>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:password>XXXXXXXXXXX</xsd:password>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:pickupDate>05/19/2017</xsd:pickupDate>

            <!--Optional:-->

            <xsd:userName>XXXXXX</xsd:userName>

         </ser:rRequest>

      </ser:getRate>

   </soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried connecting by simply using:

```
$client = new SOAPClient ( 'http://services.gts/xsd');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

but that gives me the error of `Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL`

I have a feeling the URL is not right in the sample request they sent over but not sure if I am even close. All I have read the url usually has a WSDL in the url.

Comment: so have you tried url with WSDL at the end? `http://services.gts/xsd?WSDL`

Comment: yes I have @Bart